# Spectral Line Intensities of a sample

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, electrons, photon-emission

I am doing some research on the flame test and I get the main point. I was wondering, how do you calculate the rate of photons emitted vs frequency. When I look at the Sodium emission spectrum, There are many lines and why is it such a pure yellow rather than a mix of colours. What I'm getting to is I want to be able to calculate the probability you will get a photon emitted from a sample at a specific frequency, and graph the spikes to show why the Sodium is yellow rather than white or something else. If it isn't as simple as I understand it to be, feel free to add insights to my understanding

Comment: In the question, you ask "how do you _calculate_ the rate of photons emitted vs frequency".  I don't believe this is the right terminology.  In the context of a flame test, are you asking how to _measure_ photons (flux) vs wavelength?  (More commonly, wavelength is used in this context, instead of frequency.)   If so, this is usually done with some kind of [optical spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_spectrometer).